# Explanation for tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step()

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying out programming with tensorflow and I came across this function:

```
global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step()
```

Could anyone explain to me what exactly is happening here? I found this explanation in tensorflow's documentation, but it wasn't very clear to me.

> global_step: An integer Variable representing the step counter to increment for each model training run. Can easily be created/incremented in TensorFlow via the get_global_step() function.

where `get_global_step` returns the global tensor.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the `global_step` variable.

As far as I understand, this variable is used to keep track of the current (global) training step, i.e. when you pass it to optimizers, they will increment it everytime they do an update on the parameters.

From the definition of `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize()` you can see how this works:

> global_step: Optional Variable to increment by one after the variables have been updated.

One [other use case](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics) is to save a checkpoint:

```
saver.save(sess, FLAGS.train_dir, global_step=step)
```

PS:

1. You need to define it before you can call this function. i.e.: `global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)`
2. If you have multiple trainings within the same session, this variable will be incremented by **all** optimizers.